# OpenCV check if filled

Tags: python, opencv

I need your help because of my lack of programming or mathematics. Probably both.

I wrote code that checks if a specific area in a picture is complete green. This works pretty fine. Problem it just works if my area is an rectangle which is straight to the outerlines of the picture. Now it should also work if the rectangle looks like a trapeze. For this i have four points with x and y coordinates. My current code works only with two points (top left and bottom right) for the new code i have four points (point1, point2,...).

Every of this points looks like this: point1 = (250,250)

Current Code is:

```
    for j in range(point1[1], point2[1], 15):
        for i in range(point1[0], point2[0], 15):
            if overlay[j, i][1] != 255:
                diskretisierungs_trigger = False
                break
```

Maybe you know some ideas how i can check every pixel in an specific area.

Thank you very much <3

Comment: An example image might help. I guess you could draw the polygon specified by your points as a white shape on a new, empty, black background the same size as your original image and then mask your original image with that white shape. You could then get the standard deviation of the masked image and check if it is zero - i.e. all the pixels are the same.

Comment: Similar to the above comment by Mark: I think your problem isn't checking if filled, but knowing how to check a given "Region of Interest". See [this question](https://answers.opencv.org/question/53781/roi-always-a-rectangle/) in the old OpenCV Q&A and relevant ROI sections of OpenCV tutorials. Once you understand that its a case of knowing the geometry that allows you to mask your desired shape

Comment: I'd also recommend browsing some numpy docs. very helpful in making loops disappear (hence speeding up the program). OpenCV has quite a few procedures that do equivalent things but numpy's primitives are more general (comparisons, boolean arrays, types of indexing).

Comment: @MarkSetchell this idea was pretty nice. I generated a new black image added my polygon in white and counted the zeros with numpy.count_nonzero the dark spots. Perfect Idea thank you very much :)

Comment: Cool - well done! Write it up as an answer for all to see in future and mark it as correct so you get the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MarkSetchell had a good idea. Here is how i get it done:

Generated a new image (black_image). Added my polygon in white. The rectangles now fill the black image with black and also the few white spots from the polygon after every picture i count the numbers of nonzero:

```
        pts = np.asarray(circles)
        cv2.polylines(image_new, [pts], True, red_color)
        array_size = np.shape(image_new)
        black_image = np.zeros((array_size), dtype="uint8") 
        cv2.fillPoly(black_image, [pts], color=white_color) 
        for c1, c2 in rectangles: 
            cv2.rectangle(black_image, c1, c2, black_color, -1)
        erfüllungsgrade.append(np.count_nonzero(black_image))
```