# Extract pixels within quarter circle in python

Tags: python, image-processing, medical-imaging

I have an image which I want to extract the pixels of the specific part of that. This part is a quarter circle, and my desire is to obtain the pixels of that.

I have the coordinates of the center and points which the lines connected to the circle. How is it possible to extract one quarter and ignore other parts?

Comment: Have a look at my comment here https://stackoverflow.com/q/71064466/2836621

Answer (score 2):

The disk has the equation `(X-Xc)²+(Y-Yc)²≤R²`.

The half planes meeting at the center have equations `c(X-Xc) + s(Y-Yc)≥0` where `c` and `s` are the cosine and sine of the angle.

Hence, scan the image (or just the bounding box of the circle) and consider the pixels `(X, Y)` such that the three constraints are satisfied.